# ReactDom.render not rendering the html content

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am able to transpile the jsx code but in browser its not loading anything. I am using babel and webpack too.

app.jsx

```js
const ReactDom = require('react-dom');
const React = require('react');
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello World</h1>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bundle.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './jsx/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/js/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

bundle.js

```js
------
------

(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

const ReactDom = __webpack_require__(15);
const React = __webpack_require__(4);
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
    'h1',
    { htmlFor: 'yes' },
    'Hello World'
), document.getElementById("root"));

}),

------
------
```

When I looked into html page source it showing linked to bundle.js in script tag but page is blank. 
You can check my complete project on Github [complete code](https://github.com/talkmithilesh/react-demo)

Steps I am following to run

> npm run build 
>   static (I am using node-static)

then loading index.html in browser but page is blank.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?  Without seeing your directory structure I suspect it might be a pathing issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo - `ReactDOM` should be `ReactDom`. The error that is shown in the console is `Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined`.